# Find the product $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1+x^{2n-1}) $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Find the product $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1+x^{2n-1}) $ , for example in case $|x| \le 1$

Comment: I found this problem in "Mathematical Analysis I" of Zorich, just Google Books and turn to page 149 of the preview. I believe this problem is somehow incorrectly stated (since I can't solve it :) ) , so I asked for sure.

Comment: Mathematica only gives me the QPochhamer function which is defined over such a product

Comment: it has a combinatorial meaning the resulting's powers series coefficients is the number of partions of an integer with distinct odd parts

Comment: @clark Good comment. I'm also aware of that, unfortunately it doesn't help in computing the limit.

Comment: This is [Ramanujan's chi function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RamanujanThetaFunctions.html). The coefficients of it is listed in OEIS [A000700](http://oeis.org/A000700). See comment there for places where this show up.

Comment: @Dom, alternatively, the infinite product can also be expressed in terms of Dedekind $\eta$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments below my question, it is clear that the problem is wrongly stated in the book, especially when we note that the book is a first course for students in analysis.

Comment: I don't know if this might be what was intended, but $\prod\limits_{n=1}^\infty\left(1+x^{2^{n-1}}\right)=\dfrac1{1-x}$

Comment: @robjohn 's suggestion must be what was intended, because this is collected together with three problems based on repeated doubling of $x$, and a hint to that effect.   Preview here: http://books.google.com/books?id=qA5FTMT7HE4C&pg=PA149

Comment: @zyx: This makes sense, as it is probably a simple typo (not placing the $n-1$ high enough).