# Solve an infinite product.

Tags: convergence-divergence, infinite-product

$a_n = (1+ z ^{2^{n-1}})$, where $n$ is a natural number.
Prove that
$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n = \frac{1}{1-z}$,
where $z\in \mathbf{C} \text{ and } |z| < 1$

Please help me solving this question. I tried to expand the product and use some basic identities to simplify the expansion but none of them worked. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Yes. I'm studying the convergence of Infinite Products. I've updated the question. It is to prove that the I.P is equal to 1/(1-z).

Comment: The statement is incorrect. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/350192 and a corrected version in the comment below it.

Comment: Thankyou for the information. That question was from the book 'An Introduction to Infinite Products' by Little, Teo and Brunt. (Exercise 2.2)

Comment: I corrected $a_n$  ,  now the exponent of $z$   is itself $2^{n-1}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ (1+x)(1+x^2) = 1+x + x^2 + x^3  $$
that is consecutive exponents from $0$  to $3=4-1.$

$$ (1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^4) = 1+x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5 + x^6 + x^7  $$
that is consecutive exponents from $0$  to $7 = 8-1.$

What is $$ (1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^4)(1+x^8) \; \; \; ?  \; \; \;   $$

Comment: This has been already discussed, for instance, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3251798), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3853238) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4033805).

Comment: Multiply the product with (1-z)/(1-z). Now, using a²-b², the question is done.